# Ensure two computers running the same version of the application

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

Here's my situation. I have a desktop application that interacts with sql server. There will be one sql server and multiple applications will access the same database. Currently two computers are running the same application.

If I make a change in database schema, I will also have to make a change in the application and now the problem occurs.

Before change:
Table Invoice with columns
- title varchar(128)

After change:
Table Invoice with columns
- title varchar(128)
- content varchar(128)

Computer A uses the old application that does not have any information about that new column "content" and Computer B uses the new application.

Because A is using the old app, it will insert null values to the table and B will face null pointer exception.

I cannot think of any other way since the old app cannot just terminate and download the newest version in the middle of a transaction. And I don't think it's a great idea to be like tell people don't use the app within downtime and restart the app after.

How does a website handle this? I think all of the websites will face this issue.

What is the proper way to prevent this to happen? 
Please point me to the right direction

Answer (score 1):

There are some options to do it. For example:

Using [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx) deployment, you can specify a minimum required version for the application in the `Application Updates` dialog box. You can also check it [programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx) using code while the application is running.

Also if you don't use ClickOnce, you can keep the minimum required version of your software in database and the at start of your application check the version from database and if the current version is less that minimum required version, then don't run the application. Also you can check it programmatically  while the application is running if you need.

```
var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

Comment: I can check the version at the startup but it looks like it won't work most of the times since the app will be just up and running unless people close the app.

Comment: Or as I said, you can check it while the application is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can query a record in the database that tells you what is the minimum version of the app that is compatible.

Comment: Interesting point. But if it's in a middle of a transaction, wouldn't it have the same problem? I see that I could make it check the table version at the end of the transaction

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to write a trigger for insert that would write a default value to the new column ("content). Alternatively (easier) use a default value for your column.

Comment: Hmm adding a default value sounds like a great idea. Say "total" column is added and it's default is 0.00. But this "total" column must contain the sum of the values then this approach wouldn't work right?

Comment: You can calculate the total in the trigger or have a computed column. What is your database backend?

Comment: Again: this a dirty!

Comment: You can add a default value in the table definition - a trigger isn't needed unless you are updating other tables, or as noted above, creating the value on the DB side.